# div to take remaining space whose neighbor has transform translate

Tags: css

I have two divs as shown in the image below:

[image]

In above image:

- grey rectangle is the container div.
- white rectangle is a div with transform: translateX(somevalue),
  this rectangle is draggable. So, when dragging its translateX and translateY will be changed in the code.
- blue rectangle is a div which should take up all the available width. Its height is fixed.

**I don't have any code** as I am trying to do this in react using react-draggable which uses translateX and translateY to drag an element.

**I want a pure css solution** because I don't want to re-render the component just for increasing the width of the div.

**Note:**

The blue rectangle is considered as div for the demo purpose only to make the example simpler to understand. In actual project the blue box will be a line and on that line I will put the distance between left edge of the container and left edge of the moving object. Something like a ruler.

**Update:**

Here is my code:

```
<div className="cover-print-area-settings-container">
  <div style={{ background: 'black', height: 10, width: 'auto' }} />
  <Draggable
    bounds={{
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      right: 300,
      bottom: 150
    }}
  >
    <div id="cover-print-area-draggable-content" className="cover-print-area-settings-content">
      <div className="contact-name">Contact Name</div>
      <div className="side-by-side-start-center">
        <PhoneIcon className="contact-detail-icon" />
        <span>Mobile No</span>
      </div>
      <div className="side-by-side-start-center email-wrapper">
        <EmailIcon className="contact-detail-icon" />
        <span>Email</span>
      </div>
      <div className="side-by-side-start-center">
        <LocationIcon className="contact-detail-icon contact-location-icon" />
        <div className="contact-address-wrapper">
          <p className="contact-address"> Address Line 1 </p>
          <span className="contact-address-details"> Address Line 2 </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Draggable>
</div>
```

Draggable element in the code is imported from `react-draggable`. Here is the documentation of react-draggable: https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable

The css related to the above html looks like:

```
  .cover-print-area-settings-container
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    overflow: auto
    // height: 100%
    background-color: #fff8dc
    .cover-print-area-settings-content
      border: 1px solid black
      display: inline-block
      vertical-align: top
      .contact-name
        font-size: 36px
        text-align: left    
      .contact-detail-icon
        margin-right: 7px
      .contact-location-icon
        padding-top: 12px
        align-self: flex-start
      .email-wrapper
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: -8px;
      .contact-address-wrapper
        display: flex
        flex-direction: column
        justify-content: flex-start 
        .contact-address
          text-align: left
          align-self: flex-start
        .contact-address-details
          margin-top: -12px
          text-align: left
          align-self: flex-start
```

Comment: I'm no expert on CSS translations, but given that CSS is a property of the element, I can't see how you'd manipulate CSS:translateX without Javascript mousedown, mouseup, and mousemove handling.

Comment: does this blue element holds content ? you need to share your code anyway to demonstrate your issue and failure. see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @G-Cyr Nope, blue element does not hold any content. It is a div for demonstration purpose only. It will be a line in real project and on which I will show the distance between the dragged box and the left edge of the container, so that user knows how much he has moved the box.

Comment: it would be a ruler ? , css might help, but you need to clarify the question :(

Comment: @BillDoughty Yes you are right. But I can give you an example of that. Float an image to the right and allow the text to flow around it. Now make the window smaller, The text will jump to the next line if it does not fit. That's it without javascript.

Comment: @G-Cyr exactly, it will be a ruler. I will specify it in question.'

Comment: okay, update your question, if my demo is close to your code, i might have an answer and explanation (just for the css part and blue div, draggable is javascript anyhow)

Comment: @G-Cyr I have updated my question with relevent code. Can you please take a look at it? Meanwhile I will take a look at the other answer.

Comment: @G-Cyr Thanks for the help. I have found the solution in the answer.

Comment: I saw , it is a simple trick where you can draw a ruler ... my demo was only about the pseudo ;) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dexbad , without anything to draw but a color, a shadow would have done the job

Comment: I took a look at your solution. It does not have any shadow as mentioned in the previous comment. Thanks for a helping hand.

Comment: ?? have you read correctly my earlier comment ? beside, It was only about the demo waiting to see your code , not a solution ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr I have got it to work. I will probably update the question with my answer tonight. And thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider CSS variable in this case where you simply adjust the variable that will be used for the translate and the width:

```css
.container {
  padding:20px 0;
  height:100px;
  background:grey;
}

.blue {
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
  display:inline-block;
  width:var(--c);
  margin-right:calc(var(--c) * -1);
}
.white {
height:100%;
 width:100px;
  background:white;
  display:inline-block;
  transform:translateX(var(--c));
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="--c:50px">
<div class="blue"></div><div class="white"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="--c:100px">
<div class="blue"></div><div class="white"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="--c:200px">
<div class="blue"></div><div class="white"></div>
</div>
```

Another idea would be to consider the blue part as a pseudo element of the white box and it will be easier to consider X/Y translation:

```css
.container {
  padding:20px 0;
  height:100px;
  background:grey;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.white {
height:100%;
 width:100px;
  background:white;
  display:inline-block;
  transform:translateX(var(--c));
  position:relative;
}
.white:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-100vw;
  right:100%;
  bottom:0;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="--c:50px">
<div class="blue"></div><div class="white"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="--c:100px">
<div class="blue"></div><div class="white"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="--c:200px">
<div class="blue"></div><div class="white"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your 2nd solution and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help. Can you please explain me the need of `left: -100vw` in : before pseudo element?

Comment: @Vishal there was my demo, https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dexbad i used right 100% using an absolute pseudo, so it sticks on the left side ... ;)

Comment: @Vishal the vw is the viewport width so 100vw is 100% of the screen width so I ma sure it will cover the needed space ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr you copied from me ! :p